# how to pass user input strings as xml?

Tags: asp.net, xml, api

i have a page which contains customer number, name and address which would be entered by the customer. when they press okay, i should call them and pass them as xml.

Request info API :

```
     <REQUESTINFO>
      <KEY_NAMEVALUE>
      <KEY_NAME>CUSTOMERNO</KEY_NAME>
       <KEY_VALUE>1015</KEY_VALUE>
     </KEY_NAMEVALUE>
     </REQUESTINFO>
```

Response API :

```
<RESPONSEINFO>
      <STATUS>
<TRANSACTIONNO>2433</TRANSACTIONNO>
<ERRORNO>0</ERRORNO>
<MESSAGE>SUCCESS</MESSAGE>
</STATUS>
<CUSTOMERINFO>
<CUSTOMERNO>1015</CUSTOMERNO>
<CUSTOMERTYPECODE>NORMAL</CUSTOMERTYPECODE>
<CUSTOMERTYPE>Normal</CUSTOMERTYPE>
<CATEGORYCODE>GNRL</CATEGORYCODE>
<CATEGORY>General</CATEGORY>
<INDIVIDUAL>Y</INDIVIDUAL>
<TITLE>Dr.</TITLE>
<FIRSTNAME>MIKE</FIRSTNAME>
<MIDDLENAME>JOHNSON</MIDDLENAME>
<LASTNAME>DAVID</LASTNAME>
<OPENTITYCODE>MQ</OPENTITYCODE>
<OPENTITY>company</OPENTITY>
<CURRENCYCODE>RS</CURRENCYCODE>
<CURRENCY>Rupees</CURRENCY>
<COMPANYNAME>MQSUBSCRIBE</COMPANYNAME>
<BILLINGMEDIA>EP</BILLINGMEDIA>
<PARENT>Y</PARENT>
<GROUPID></GROUPID>
<NOTES>VALUABLE</NOTES>
<CONTACTINFO>
<CONTACTNAME>JOHNSON</CONTACTNAME>
<EMAIL>MIKEJOHNSON@company.COM</EMAIL>
<ALTEMAIL></ALTEMAIL>
<HOMEPHONE>2012326562</HOMEPHONE>
<WORKPHONE>2016654556</WORKPHONE>
<MOBILEPHONE>2014563215</MOBILEPHONE>
<FAXNBR>56456455665</FAXNBR>
</CONTACTINFO>
<ADDRESSINFO>
<ADDRESSTYPECODE>PRI</ADDRESSTYPECODE>
<ADDRESS1>#12B</ADDRESS1>
<ADDRESS2></ADDRESS2>
<STREET>JAMESSTREET</STREET>
<AREA>LAKEVIEW</AREA>
<CITY>BUENAPARK</CITY>
<DISTRICT></DISTRICT>
<STATE>CALIFORNIA</STATE>
<ZIPCODE>90621</ZIPCODE>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<ADDRESSTYPECODE>BIL</ADDRESSTYPECODE>
<ADDRESS1>#12B</ADDRESS1>
<ADDRESS2></ADDRESS2>
<STREET>JAMESSTREET</STREET>
<AREA>LAKEVIEW</AREA>
<CITY>BUENAPARK</CITY>
<DISTRICT></DISTRICT>
<STATE>CALIFORNIA</STATE>
<ZIPCODE>90621</ZIPCODE>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
</ADDRESSINFO> 
<FLEX-ATTRIBUTE-INFO>
<ATTRIBUTE1></ATTRIBUTE1>
<ATTRIBUTE2></ATTRIBUTE2>
<ATTRIBUTE3></ATTRIBUTE3>
<ATTRIBUTE4></ATTRIBUTE4>
<ATTRIBUTE5></ATTRIBUTE5>
<ATTRIBUTE6></ATTRIBUTE6>
<ATTRIBUTE7></ATTRIBUTE7>
<ATTRIBUTE8></ATTRIBUTE8>
<ATTRIBUTE9></ATTRIBUTE9>
<ATTRIBUTE10></ATTRIBUTE10>
</FLEX-ATTRIBUTE-INFO>
<CONTRACTINFO>
<CONTRACTNO>2024</CONTRACTNO>
<STARTDATE>14-10-2009</STARTDATE>
<ENDDATE>14-10-2009</ENDDATE>
<CONTRACTSTATUS>Active</CONTRACTSTATUS>
<ISBULK></ISBULK >
<BILLFREQUENCY></BILLFREQUENCY>
<SALESMANCODE></SALESMANCODE>
<NOOFROOMS></NOOFROOMS>
<OUTLETS></OUTLETS>
<NOTES></NOTES>
<PLANINFO>
<PLANCODE>WEBPLAN</PLANCODE>
<SERVICEINFO>
<SERVICECODE></SERVICECODE>
<OUTLETS></OUTLETS>
</SERVICEINFO>
<SERVICEGROUPINFO>
<SERVICEGROUPCODE></SERVICEGROUPCODE>
<OUTLETS></OUTLETS >
<SERVICEINFO>
<SERVICECODE></SERVICECODE>
</SERVICEINFO>
</SERVICEGROUPINFO>
<PACKAGEINFO>
<PACKAGECODE></PACKAGECODE>
<OUTLETS> </OUTLETS >
<SERVICEGROUPINFO>
<SERVICEGROUPCODE></SERVICEGROUPCODE>
<SERVICEINFO>
<SERVICECODE></SERVICECODE>
</SERVICEINFO>
</SERVICEGROUPINFO>
<SERVICEINFO>
<SERVICECODE></SERVICECODE>
</SERVICEINFO>
</PACKAGEINFO>
<PACKAGEGROUPINFO>
<PACKAGEGROUPCODE></PACKAGEGROUPCODE>
<OUTLETS></OUTLETS >
<PACKAGEINFO>
<PACKAGECODE></PACKAGECODE>
<SERVICEGROUPINFO>
<SERVICEGROUPCODE></SERVICEGROUPCODE>
<SERVICEINFO>
<SERVICECODE></SERVICECODE>
</SERVICEINFO>
</SERVICEGROUPINFO>
<SERVICEINFO>
<SERVICECODE></SERVICECODE>
</SERVICEINFO>`enter code here`
</PACKAGEINFO>
</PACKAGEGROUPINFO>
</PLANINFO>
</CONTRACTINFO>
</CUSTOMERINFO>
</RESPONSEINFO>
```

out put should be as like above. need clarification on this????

Comment: Just use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: i am just looking for a way to start.. not the code.. i just want to do it, not others..

Comment: Then check the link I posted.